Kids getting caught up in a war
I saw a movie a few years ago, where some kids were fooling around in the desert, and then suddenly weird things happen that suggest a war starting, or some kind of foreign occupation taking place. I remember it took place in Australia. I think the movie was a miniseries.
Did anyone see it? What's the name of the movie?

I think the answer is 'Tomorrow when the world began', based on a series of books by John Marsden.
Think it was a film rather than a miniseries, but there may have been sequels because there's quite a few books. It's about 5 years old now.
Hope that helps
Just checked on wiki
Australian, foreign invasion, teenagers become guerrillas.
Made in 2010
